# How to get the current timezone of a hadoop file system

Tags: hadoop

I want to find out which timezone the hadoop filesystem is in.

More specifically, I want to know which timezone the date returned by `hadoop fs -ls` command is.

Is there any command/api to retrieve this?

My problem stems from the fact that the date returned by the `hadoop fs -stat` command is always in UTC ([doc link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#stat)), and I want to convert this time to the hadoop filesystem time so that my calculations are in sync

Answer (score 1):

Since HDFS use just UTC as a simple format (see [stat source on github](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/03cfc852791c14fad39db4e5b14104a276c08e59/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/Stat.java)):

```
 protected final SimpleDateFormat timeFmt;
  {
    timeFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    timeFmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  }
```

So you need just convert it using bash or any other script. You can get epoch time by `%Y` option from `stat` command. Now you can **remove last three digit** from epoch and convert it to your local time by `date -d`.

```
~$ ./hadoop-3.2.2/bin/hadoop fs -stat %Y /majid3
~$ date -d @1622704617
```

You can do it in a single bash command (in ubuntu 20)

```
mydate=`./hadoop-3.2.2/bin/hadoop fs -stat %Y /yourpathtofile` && date -d @$(echo "($mydate + 500)/1000" | bc)
```